# Value does not fall within the expected range when calling REST web service in windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I've been struggling for hours on this one. I keep getting "Value does not fall within the expected range" when I call one of my web service functions. I'm using a POST method to which I'm passing a json object and expecting some json data to be returned.

It doesn't make sense as I've got other web service functions working perfectly well and most annoyingly, it works a perfectly when called from Fiddler 2.

I'm calling the following code in a try/catch

```
string jsonResponse = await wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(App.WebServiceUri + "/json/getdocumentbydocid"), jsonRequest);
```

I've put break points in my code and when called from fiddler, it goes into the specific function but when called through code, it generates the exception "Value does not fall within the expected range" but it isn't caught in the try/catch

It bombs out straight to

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs
```

e)

Maybe it's not being caught by the try/catch because I'm calling this from an async function:

```
public static Task<string> UploadStringTaskAsync(this WebClient wc, Uri url, string data)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    wc.UploadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
            tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
        else if (e.Cancelled)
            tcs.TrySetCanceled();
        else
            tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
    };

    wc.UploadStringAsync(url, "POST", data);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

but it still doesn't explain my error. I'm not dealing with any list or similar, so again I have to assume that it's something related to the uri, but that's not it either!

After I the error is caught in Application_UnhandledException, and continue running the app, it actually calls my code and returns the appropriate data but my app has bombed out.

It just doesn't make sense! The json object pass is a simple poco object which contains a string (table name), a long (docid) and a int (page no) and it returns a poco object, again none containing list or similar, so I don't understand what this error mean and why does it work perfectly for every other functions defined in my web service.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

This is the second time I'm changing this answer!! I deleted my original one and I thought I had it fixed and provided the details but it wasn't the correct reason.

I'm so fed up getting this wrong but at least I'm learning something in the process but the error still doesn't make sense, well at least not to me!

I thought it was related to dodgy xaml, or not having a lazy load when calling my async function from the constructor, but that's not the case.

While I had dodgy code, I'm pretty sure now that I've cleared it up and all is set up as expected but I'm still getting the error.

I have a third-party control that needs to be on a UserControl. My UserControl has a single property i.e. SourceFile of type string

```
public string SourceFile
{
    get
    {
        return _sourceFile;
    }
    set
    {
        _sourceFile = value;
    }
}
```

This property is binded to a property from my viewModel i.e. DocumentUri

```
public string DocumentUri
{
    get { return this._documentUri; }
    set
    {
        if (this._documentUri != value)
        {
            this.SetProperty(ref this._documentUri, value);
        }
    }
}
```

The SetProperty takes care of the INotifyPropertyChanged and my event handler is definitely being set.

Now here is my xaml code:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <cc:Viewer SourceFile="{Binding DocumentUri}" />
    </StackPanel>                        
 </Grid>
```

Where cc:Viewer is my UserControl.

When set as the above, I get the following error: "Value does not fall within the expected range."

If I remove the SourceFile="{Binding DocumentUri}", the error disappears but that's pointless as I need this property to display my document when it is downloaded. It just confirms that it is in fact linked to this property.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Thierry

Comment: Are there any more detailos about the exception if you trace into  Application_UnhandledException.

Comment: Source, StackTrace and InnerException are null. The only thing that's filled is Message. {System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.}
    [System.ArgumentException]: {System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HelpLink: null
    HResult: -2147024809
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Value does not fall within the expected range."
    Source: null
    StackTrace: null

Comment: @Thierry try Debug.WriteLine("") in your UploadStringTaskAsync method, also maybe the method should not be Static??? try using a non static method and see if it works.

Comment: @user2653208 The reason my UploadStringTaskAsynch is static is that it is an extension function, but I'll give it a shot and update tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: @Thierry Did you try?? did it work?? EDIT: Maybe the error is not in the function. Did you check the Locals tab while the application reaches the breakpoint in ApplicationUnhandledException method

Comment: @user2653208 I started transferring code to a console application just see how it would be have from there but same thing. It bombs out the console without errors. I then removed the static function altogether and change my code accordingly and it still doesn't work. I then removed the async call and use the synchronous method and this works! I need to spend more time on this as I just don't understand how does it work perfectly for Login, GetConfig and Search web services functions which are all designed the same way and use the same WebClient extension so it still doesn't add up.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted my original answer as I just spotted what was causing the problem and this time I'm 100% sure of it.

While I thought it was maybe related to dodgy xaml, or not having a lazy load when calling my async function from the constructor, it was a combination of things.

The error thrown is totally misleading!! It was due to a combination of things:

1. Calling an async from the constructor without using the Asynchronous Initialization Pattern.
2. Not checking if values were blank in my constructor and properties
3. Creating a property in my UserControl which wasn't binded. I just created a regular property when I should have in fact have created a property using DepencyProperty to make it bindable.

Once all of the above were correct, my problem got sorted.